# VSTS Web performance Test-how to record AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I am new to VSTS and trying to create a Web performance test.
I started recording using VS 13 update 5.
The Application contains AJAX calls.
Problem is, while recording the application it captures a lot of URLs and it is difficult to do further steps (parameterization/customization).
How can I record AJAX calls using VSTS?

Answer (score 0):

When deal with ajax call first we need to know from the application what event that trigger the ajax call, in the image below i have one button that trigger the ajax call to controller and pass some data to it. I use ASP.Net MVC.

You can use any tools to monitor, for me i just use tools from chrome (press F12) and from the network i can see the event that trigger by the button click, and from tab preview or response you can see the ajax call and the data that being pass from that call and if your ajax call will return a result you also can monitor that return value using this.

Hope this will help

Regards
rg

[image: sample ajax call]